# XML Deserialization on IIS using XmlSchemaSet extremely slow (ASP.NET 4.6.2)

Tags: c#, iis, serialization, xsd, xml-deserialization

I'm having a problem with extremely slow XML Deserialization in ASP.NET 4.6.2. 
A string containing XML needs to be deserialized using a XmlSchemaSet, which works fine within our own development environment, but for some reason our customer running the same code, with the same XML on IIS (windows server 2012 r2, so IIS 8.5 i presume) has extreme delays: **Retrieving the Schemaset takes 20 seconds, and deserializing the XML takes 40 seconds**, even though the same code can deserialize other XML/Schemas without any delays.
Because the code runs on a remote secure environment I have difficulty debugging the problem, and I can't seem to reproduce the problem locally.

This code was extensively tested locally, in unittests and runnning on IIS, and in all cases it worked flawlessly, even when using the same Xml schemaset and the same data. 
Our logging systems see no exceptions or errors. I would like to scan any events using ProcMon, but I currently have no access to the hosting environment :-( 
The schemaset consists of 6 XSD files with around a 100 types/templates, so not excessive. The xml file is around 72 lines long.

```
public static object DeSerializeClassFromString(string xml, Type targetType, XmlSchemaSet schema)
{
    XmlReaderSettings settings = null;
    if (schema != null)
    {
        settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
        settings.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema;
        settings.ValidationFlags =
                XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ProcessIdentityConstraints |
                XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ReportValidationWarnings | XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ProcessInlineSchema;
        settings.ValidationEventHandler += new ValidationEventHandler(DeSerializeClassFromString_ValidationEventHandler);
        settings.Schemas.Add(schema);
    }
    // Use an xmlTextReader to get the proper encoding for the xml
    XmlReader reader = XmlTextReader.Create(new XmlTextReader(new StringReader(xml)), settings);
    object res = DeSerializeClass(reader, targetType);
    return res;
}

public void TestFunction(string xml)
{
    var xss = new System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaSet();
    xss.Add(@"http://www.hostname.nl/schema/Messages/2010/02/Header",
        XmlReader.Create(new MemoryStream(Properties.Resources.resource1)));
    xss.Add(@"http://www.hostname.nl/schema/Messages/2010/02/Types",
        XmlReader.Create(new MemoryStream(Properties.Resources.resource2)));

    var obj = DeSerializeClassFromString(xml, typeof(myType), xss);
}
```

I expect the code to be run within several milliseconds, not 40 seconds.

Comment: Have you checked the load on his server? Maybe you are using nice modern machines and he's running an old dog (presumably so with WS2012) with 4GB memory, mostly in use. Maybe he's using full SQL Server and not managing the memory allocation. Also, you mention secure network - if the files are being retrieved over a network, maybe that is misconfigured, so extremely slow. I'd be looking more into the server/ hosting environment if the code runs fine for you.

Comment: Hi @hockeyJ, the files are all local. The schemas are stored in the resource files for the assembly, and the XML is in the string.
I've added logging to check the timing, and the delay is purely in the call to DeSerializeClassFromString, and seems to be exactly 42 seconds, every-single-time, so it isn't simply load-related